# How to extract data from list stored as a string like a list?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have coordinates as keys in dict and want to read them like a normal list when I try to extract them. See example:

```
testlist = {'[0, 0]': 0, '[1 ,1]': 1}

for tmp in testlist:
   if testlist[tmp] == 1:
      print(tmp[0], tmp[1])
```

The above example should return

> 1 1

However it outputs

> [ 1

I tried `list(tmp)` and `tmp.split()` but neither gave the desired output. There probably exists an easy solution, but I could not find it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate the strings when needed, converting them to lists.  For example:

```
import ast

testlist = {'[0, 0]': 0, '[1 ,1]': 1}

for key in testlist:
    if testlist[key] == 1:
        tmp = ast.literal_eval(key)
        print(tmp[0], tmp[1])
```

This produces the desired result:

```
1 1
```

Note that `ast.literal_eval` is a restricted form of eval that is safe from harmful side effects.

Comment: In this specific case, `json.loads()` might be better.

Comment: @JohnGordon It depends on where the data is coming from and what other forms it might take.  If it's just two-element lists of integers, then `ast.literal_eval` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works without imports:

```
testlist = {'[0, 0]': 0, '[1 ,1]': 1}

for tmp in testlist:
   if testlist[tmp] == 1:
        test = list(tmp.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").split())
        print(int(test[0]), int(test[1]))
```

But there're definitely better solutions lol